# Tensorflow 2.0.0-alpha0: tf.logging.set_verbosity

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've installed tensorflow `2.0.0-alpha0`. When trying to set logging verbosity with the `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)` command, I got the following error:

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'.

Are there some changes with this point in the `2.0.0-alpha0` version?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `TensorFlow 2.0` you can still access `tf.logging` via `tf.compat.v1`:

```
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

**EDIT**

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180827-api-names.md), in the *Deprecated namespaces*, it is suggested to use Python `logging` module:

> tf.logging - Python `logging` module can be used instead.

So you should use:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

before importing `tensorflow`.

Comment: Why before importing tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

As per official documentation

> Many APIs are either gone or moved in TF 2.0. Some of the major
>   changes include removing tf.app, tf.flags, and tf.logging

https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/effective_tf2