# Is there any substitute of logging attribute in Tensorflow in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, image-processing, python-3.7

While using the `logging` attribute in TensorFlow in Python 3 I am getting an error that the attribute is invalid.
What can I use instead of it?
Error:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'
```

Comment: Check  this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081911/tensorflow-2-0-0-alpha0-tf-logging-set-verbosity

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow2 tf.logging is removed. tf.logging is for looging and summary.

[tf_upgrade_v2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/upgrade) will upgrade script and changes `tf.logging` to `tf.compat.v1.logging`